# Return data to a webhook in Woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce, webhooks, shopping-cart, price

Is it possible to return data to a WooCommerce webhook.

I have a webshop in WooCommerce. This is linked to a local administration. Because we have a complicated discount system, we cannot accommodate it in WooCommerce. I would like to send the contents of the shopping cart from WooCommerce to a local web service. This web service can calculate the prices and discounts of the items and send it back to WooCommerce so that it can calculate the total price of the cart again.

Is this possible or do I still need to create this via a filter in the function.php?

I searched Google for a solution but could not find one. The webhook works, but I cannot return data or do not know the format of this data.